# Pip3 not working at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3, pip

So a couple days ago, I had a problem where pip3 just stopped working. I was planning on upgrading my WSL2 anyway, so I just migrated to Ubuntu 20. But the same problem has occurred here too! I can't install *anything* with pip3.
[image: Pip not working!]

Using -vvv yields the exact same results- nothing. I've already tried reinstalling:

`sudo apt purge *python3-pip* && sudo apt install python3-pip`

Yes, I've waited about 20 minutes and nothing happens. The help menu works when I run `pip3`, the `pip3 freeze` command works, but install & uninstall does not. Probably irrelevant, but here's the message when I get when I kill it with Ctrl+C:

```
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import SessionCommandMixin
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.network.auth import MultiDomainBasicAuth
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 36, in <module>
    import keyring  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 189, in <module>
    init_backend()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 93, in init_backend
    keyrings = filter(limit, backend.get_all_keyring())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/__init__.py", line 21, in wrapper
    func.always_returns = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 210, in get_all_keyring
    return list(rings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/__init__.py", line 31, in suppress_exceptions
    for callable in callables:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 67, in viable
    cls.priority
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/kwallet.py", line 140, in priority
    return super(DBusKeyringKWallet4, cls).priority - 1
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 26, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backends/kwallet.py", line 37, in priority
    bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=DBusGMainLoop())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 212, in __new__
    return Bus.__new__(cls, Bus.TYPE_SESSION, private=private,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 102, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 124, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/exceptions.py", line 47, in __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm stumped! This is a very annoying error. In case it matters, I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the Microsoft Store. Thank you!

Comment: Not certain how you would approach this, but the version of `pip` in your traceback seems old (`20.0.2`). [The most recent version of `pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is currently `21.0.1`, released at the end of January 2021. This could be an issue.

Comment: @Anaksunaman How would I update pip? I'm simply getting it from the official Ubuntu repositories. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip` but it just said `python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1).` Running `python3 -m pip install -U pip` hangs as well and doesn't produce any output.

Comment: You may also want to Google something like "[pip WSL2 Ubuntu hangs](https://www.google.com/search?q=pip+wsl2+ubuntu+hangs)" since there are also other possible explanations for this behavior as well.

Comment: @Anaksunaman When I run the command you sent, it says `no such option: -m`. Well, thanks for trying

Comment: That was an error. Apologies. Not sure why my brain misfired like that.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out thanks to Anaksunaman in the comments. I followed [this post](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9061) on GitHub, and it worked!

It turns out, the problem was exporting the DISPLAY variable for my X-Server that I was using. Once I commented that line out from .bashrc, pip works again.

I would appreciate if someone could explain *why* this line was breaking it in the comments:

`export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2; exit;}'):0.0`

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. =)